# Thinktecture Identity Server and Azure AD B2C Policy Parameter

Tags: identityserver3, azure-ad-b2c

I am working to add Azure Active Directory B2C as an external provider.  I am able to do a generic configuration and it works just fine.  But when I want to send the policy paramter {p} it messes up the query string going to microsoft.  It looks like this ?p=policyname?clientid=....

Any suggestions on how to include the policy name in the request coming from identity server to microsoft azure?

Comment: Hello! Did you ever figure out how to get this working? I am in the same position and am curious as to how the policy query string can be passed along...